# Java array/2 Dimensional Array User Input and Display

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to write a method that allows the user to input the number of players on a sports team, the number of games played, the names of the players, and the amount of points scored per player per game.

Basically, I want the following display output where all information has been provided by the user:

```
Player  Game 1  Game 2  Game 3  Game 4
Tom
Dick
Harry
Matthew
John
```

... and then points scored by each player in each game.

I admit that this little project originated from a homework assignment, but I've already turned the assignment in and the assignment didn't even ask for user supplied input.  I really just want to know how to do this.

Below is my code.  A few problems.

1. I assign each player's name to an array called `playerRoster`.  Don't all array initialize at `arrayName[0]`?  But when I print out `playerRoster[0]`, nothing displays.  When I print out `playerRoster[1]`, the first name I enter for the array (which should be indexed at `playerRoster[0]`) displays.  Why?
2. Related to above: I am prompted to enter the number of players on roster, and say I enter the number 5.  But the prompt then allows me to only enter 4 names.  Why?
3. The display above is what I'm looking for, and I'm sure there are built in Java methods for displaying a table of values.  I actually don't want that.  I kind of want to go forward with loops, like I'm doing now. (I know, I know - beggars can't be choosers)

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class BasketballScores
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
    System.out.println ("Enter the number of players on roster: ");
    int numPlayers = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Enter the number of games played: ");
    int numGames = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    int[][] arrayScores = new int[numPlayers][numGames];
    String[] playerRoster = new String[numPlayers];
    System.out.println ("Enter player names: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < numPlayers; j++)
    {
        playerRoster[j] = input.nextLine();
    }
    for (String element: playerRoster)
    {
        System.out.println (element);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Enter the points scored per player per game: ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print (playerRoster[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < numGames; k++)
        {
            arrayScores[i][k] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int k = 0; k < numGames; k++)
        {
            System.out.print (arrayScores[i][k] + ", ");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your input please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, before you get your player names, you are still on the line with the `numGames`. You need to call `input.nextLine()` before attempting to parse your names. This should solve your first 2 questions. What happens with `#nextLine` is you are going to the end of the line of the current line you are on. After you get your  `numGames` you are still on that line. Call `input.nextLine()` to advance to the lines with your player names.

```
System.out.println ("Enter the number of players on roster: ");
int numPlayers = input.nextInt();
System.out.println();
System.out.println ("Enter the number of games played: ");
int numGames = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); //You need this to go to the next line before attempting to get your player names. 
System.out.println();
int[][] arrayScores = new int[numPlayers][numGames];
String[] playerRoster = new String[numPlayers];
System.out.println ("Enter player names: ");
for (int j = 0; j < numPlayers; j++)
{
    playerRoster[j] = input.nextLine();
}
```

For formatting your print you can use `System.out.printf`. Here is a quick example for your situation that you should be able to utilize.  [Quick reference guide](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf)

```
String[] players = new String[]{"Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Matthew", "Johh"};
System.out.printf("%-10s%6s%6s%6s%6s","Player", "Game1 ", "Game2 ", "Game3 ", "Game4 ");
System.out.println();
Random r = new Random();
for (String player : players){
    System.out.printf("%-10s%3d%6d%6d%6d",player, r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10), r.nextInt(10));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
Player    Game1 Game2 Game3 Game4 
Tom         2     9     7     3
Dick        8     1     8     4
Harry       9     2     0     2
Matthew     5     1     3     2
Johh        8     4     0     2
```

Once you share how you are trying to input your data, I can help a little more. Hope this helps!

Comment: Gonzo, thanks so much for your help.  I was able to fix how the name displays because of your suggestion, so that was a big help.

Comment: You asked how I intend to input my data.  Perhaps I'm don't understand the question correctly, but is this not the input for my data?:

Comment: System.out.println ("Enter the number of players on roster: ");
    int numPlayers = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println ("Enter the number of games played: ");
    int numGames = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    int[][] arrayScores = new int[numPlayers][numGames];
    String[] playerRoster = new String[numPlayers];
    System.out.println ("Enter player names: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < numPlayers; j++)
    {
        playerRoster[j] = input.nextLine();
    }

Comment: I just meant where are we getting the names from and the scores? How is this data formatted? I was just assuming your player names were on the next line.

Comment: @willie_h also feel free to accept my answer if it helped solve your problem. :)

Comment: Both names and scores are user-supplied.  I guess they can be anything.  You can have a player named Barney the Big Dumb Purple Dinosaur score 120,412 points in Game 3, for instance.

Comment: How do I accept?  You have to excuse me.  I'm new to posting here at stackoverflow.  But you have been very helpful.

Comment: [How to accept?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429992/how-to-accept-an-answer-to-my-post) Glad I was able to help out. :) Welcome to SO.